# Discord bot import module error after downloading the discord module

Tags: python, discord

[I am trying to make a discord bot, and I have installed the discord.py through the python pip. However, VSCODE throw an importerror and ask me to download the discord.py again. How should I fix the issue. Thank you very much!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAjhh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be some error on their end not yours. I don't see anything in your code that's trying to import a module named disco. Try saving, closing VSCode, opening it back up and rerunning your code. Sometimes it is a bit behind in processing what you've typed. Also, I would suggest not displaying your bot's token in a screenshot. You should probably go change it if that's your real token.